# GMAIL APP -: Google SMTP Error: 454 4.7.0 Too many login attempts, please try again later

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, google-apps

While it was possible to use Gmail/Google Apps as an SMTP server for scripted use or in any other Apps.
I started getting error messages:

```
SMTP Error: 454 4.7.0 Too many login attempts, please try again later.
```

Sometimes you get, sometimes you don't get such error.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is because of Google Apps Security.
You Can't use same E-mail ID with more than 2 Apps.
as Gmail needs to sync it, and it is Obvious to receive such error.

Even setting SPF/TXT/DKIM record is not enough for it.

So try to use different E-Mail IDs for Different Apps.

Comment: what do you mean by E-mail IDs?

Comment: The email address that is used for the login

Answer (score 0):

Since we are using gmail to send email, we need to enable "less secure access" on the gmail account. Log out from all the Google accounts from the browser. Login in to the gmail account configured in application.properties. Then click on this [link and turn on access for less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps). In some cases, you may need to access this [link](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) as well! If you don't follow these steps, you will get the following error,

```
org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again.

Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 454 4.7.0 Too many login attempts, please try again later. m1sm1809073wmq.36 - gsmtp
```

Note that the password for your account should not be an ordinary password, but an application password generated for your google account. Follow [this link to see the details and to generate your Google App Password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833).

**Note:** Google now requires that you have 2-Step-Verification enabled before you can set up an application password.

[How to Create an App Password for Gmail](https://devanswers.co/create-application-specific-password-gmail/)