# password command failed error with PhpMailer

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am using phpMailer for a long time and it was working fine till today.
On debugging, I am getting this log:

```
    2018-09-20 11:15:07 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP n22-v6sm46372542pfj.68 - gsmtp
2018-09-20 11:15:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 192.168.11.32
2018-09-20 11:15:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [202.166.206.49]
                                      250-SIZE 35882577
                                      250-8BITMIME
                                      250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
                                      250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                      250-PIPELINING
                                      250-CHUNKING
                                      250 SMTPUTF8
2018-09-20 11:15:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2018-09-20 11:15:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2018-09-20 11:15:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: Z3Jvd2J5ZGF0YS5ucEBnbWFpbC5jb20=
2018-09-20 11:15:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2018-09-20 11:15:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: ISEkdW1tZXJAMTA4ISE=
2018-09-20 11:15:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 454 4.7.0 Too many login attempts, please try again later. n22-v6sm46372542pfj.68 - gsmtp
2018-09-20 11:15:08 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 454 4.7.0 Too many login attempts, please try again later. n22-v6sm46372542pfj.68 - gsmtp
2018-09-20 11:15:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2018-09-20 11:15:08 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2018-09-20 11:15:08 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
2018-09-20 11:15:08 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

I am using GMAIL SMTP.

I could assume from the error : `Too many login attempts` that many emails sending limit for the day has expired.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Maybe this is your solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367327/gmail-too-many-login-attempts

Comment: No, I don't think it's a sending limit, it's that you've had too many login failures, so gmail is blocking your logins to prevent your account being hacked. You need to change your password because you have exposed it here in a format that's easy decoded. This also tells me that you're using an old version of PHPMailer, so you should update, though that won't fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing TCP port to 587 from 25 in Outbound Connections settings in SMTP Server

check similarly error has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40550149/smtp-error-454-4-7-0-too-many-login-attempts-please-try-again-later) previously